# Unable to run Punjab

Tags: python, xmpp, strophe

I downloaded [Punjab from Github](https://github.com/twonds/punjab). I also have Python 2.7, Twisted Python 10.2, OpenSSL required to run Punjab. I was able to install Punjab successfully but while running it reports "twistd is not recognised as an internal or external command"

I have no knowledge of python; could someone please tell me what to do?

Comment: @Kavya: How did you install it?

Comment: @diecho...Its a connection manager....                                 @sukhbir...i unzipped the files nd used python setup.py install to install punjab..

Comment: @Kavya: It should be `twisted` not `twistd`. Can you show the code that is throwing this error?

Comment: @sukhbir... Initially i tried with the command                    twistd -y punjab.tac                                                 It said twistd is not recognised as internal or external command...    I also tried twisted -y punjab.tac,I ended up vit the same error... u can see the punjab files at https://github.com/twonds/punjab

Comment: @Kavya: Aah, ok. Have you configured the `punjab.tac` file?

Comment: got it running..I ran the command python twistd.py -y C:\twonds-punjab-e4a0ad5\punjab.tac...... ran both together..It worked:):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed twisted? http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

If you have then it seems like it is not in your execution path.

Answer (score 1):

"twistd is not recognised as an internal or external command", if you are using `windows os` 
this is mean that the twistd is not in the PATH of searching  ( environement variabls).

You must add the twistd scripts folder path to **windows PATH** 
for example :

if the twistd is in this path =`'c:\python27\lib\site_package\twistd'` 

right click on your 
`my computer icon -> proporietes -> advaced(tab) ->click "envirment variables"`

search for PATH in the list of **"system variables"** and add your path 
`"c:\python25\lib\site_package\twistd\scripts"`